# What rule ILSVRC use to split into train and val datasets?

Tags: dataset, caffe, training-data, imagenet

I am new to imagenet and the ILSVRC datasets.

In my previous studies, I often use k-fold validation to avoid overfitting, but it seem for the ILSVRC dataset, the train, val, test datasets are already split.

But I did not find any documents explaining how they split the datasets.

Is there any websites or paper for this question?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Training a deep neural network for image classification takes a lot of time. If your model trains for weeks you will not want to use k-fold cross validation.

See this [link](http://cs231n.github.io/classification/#val) for a detailed description of train, validation and test datasets. For a good introduction to image classification with CNNs I also recommend you working through the whole [course](http://cs231n.github.io/).